# NotSerializableException error on Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have an xml file and trying to clone each repo defined in that file.
So I created the script below,(some part)

```
manifest.project.each { project ->
  def repo = project.@repo.text()
  def branch = project.@branch.text()
  sh "mkdir -p $path && cd $path && git clone --branch $branch https://test.github.com/repo/${path}.git"
```

So I want to create a directory first and then clone this repo there. But it gives me the error below;

```
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:926)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
```

How can I fix this?